# Undefined index in php with form type range

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Not sure why form input type range is handled any different than a text field... but I get Undefined index on all my range selectors!

JavaScript:

```
function outputUpdate(obj) {
    obj.previousElementSibling.value = obj.value;
}
```

in php:

```
$entrynum = $_POST['entrynum'];
$class = $_POST['class'];

$paint = $_POST['paint'];
$wheels = $_POST['wheels'];
$mods = $_POST['mods'];
$engine = $_POST['engine'];
```

in form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="entrynum">Registration</label>
    <input type="number" name="entrynum" id="entrynum" value="" required="true" placeholder="" />
    <label for="class">Classification</label>
    <input type="text" name="class" id="class" value="" required="true" placeholder="" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h3>Paint / Body</h3></legend>
        <output for="paint" id="paint">0</output>
        <input id="paint" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" list="0-10" oninput="outputUpdate(this)">
    </fieldset>
    ...repeated for all sliders...
</form>
```

- Notice: Undefined index: paint
- Notice: Undefined index: wheels
- Notice: Undefined index: mods
- Notice: Undefined index: engine

...you get the point...

entrynum and class work just fine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: I don't see a `name` attribute on  your **paint** input field. PHP picks up form posts by the name attribute, not the id.

Comment: it must be name in html form rather than id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Form there are no fields with the `name` corresponding to those:

```
$_POST['paint'];
$_POST['wheels'];
$_POST['mods'];
$_POST['engine'];
```

Thus they are undefined.

Those are just Notices and so the code still works. If you want them to be gone, do something to define those fields. Either define them yourself in PHP or put them in your Form.

Answer (score 2):

No **name attribute** in your `<input type="range">`. Put that.. It will work well..

Same thing goes for all your elements which are not being fetched in php..

And if you are processing the form on the same php... just leave the method empty..